Why PBI report is not refreshed after refreshing semantic model?
I applied incremental refresh in my report, everything is set up correctly. I checked 'Detect data changes' and chose ModificationDate column as the base one for data change comparison. I publish report to PBi Service. Then, just to test the whole mechanism, I make changes on SQL table for the last 3 months. Now I would like to see if changes were detected in PBI Service report. I go to PBI Service, refresh semantic model manually, then open report and no changes are visible. What I noticed is that if I refresh report page using F5 then all changes appear in visualizations. I don't know why that happens.
I read somewhere that 'typically, if a report is viewed after a scheduled dataset refresh, Power BI Service will display the latest data. However, manual refreshes don't always trigger automatic report view updates for active sessions'
Is that true or perhaps I need to change some settings in PBI Service? Automatic refresh will give me the latest data?
